# Python: Count instances of a specific character in all rows within a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, count

I have a dataframe (df) containing columns ['toaddress',  'ccaddress', 'body']

I want to iterate through the index of the dataframe to get the min, max, and average amount of email addresses in toaddress and ccaddress fields as determined by counting the instance of and '@' within each field in those two columns

If all else fails, i guess I could just use df.toaddress.str.contains(r'@').sum() and divide that by the number of rows in the data frame to get the average, but  I think it's just counting the rows that at least have 1 @ sign.

Comment: Can you provide a few rows of the data frame?

Comment: It wont let me post the image of the rows :(  but in first column is an unlabled index starting at 0 and going to over 400k rows.  The column toaddress has email addresses seperated by commas and sometimes \null

Comment: Note that you suggest using `df.toaddress.str.contains(r'@').sum()` why not use `df.toaddress.str.count(r'@')` if you're happy going column by column? I added an answer to do it across more than one column in one step.

Comment: @Mr. F - great point and that's what worked best. Thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
df[['toaddress', 'ccaddress']].applymap(lambda x: str.count(x, '@'))
```

to get back the count of `'@'` within each cell.

Then you can just compute the pandas `max`, `min`, and `mean` along the row axis in the result.

As I commented on the original question, you already suggested using `df.toaddress.str.contains(r'@').sum()` -- why not use `df.toaddress.str.count(r'@')` if you're happy going column by column instead of the method I showed above?

Comment: Thank you.  To answer your question I didn't think of count(r'@')...good point. Then I can append it with .max  .mean  .min    Excellent Point! It works.  I'll also study the applymap method - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
len(filter(lambda df: df.toaddress.str.contains(r'@'),rows))
```

or even

```
len(filter(lambda df: r'@' in str(df.toaddress), rows))
```

Comment: How does the "rows" come into play?

Comment: rows would be whatever you use to iterate over the rows of your output.  the main point was to use filter on each row and then get the count of the the ones that the filter lets through with len()

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this

```
from pandas import *
import re

df = DataFrame({"emails": ["fake@gmail.com, example@gmail.com", 
                           "KingArthur@aol.com, none, SirRobyn@msn.net, TheBlackKnight@clintonserver.com"]})

at = re.compile(r"@", re.I)
def count_emails(string):
    count = 0
    for i in at.finditer(string):
        count += 1
    return count

df["count"] = df["emails"].map(count_emails)

df
```

Returns:

```
    emails                                                  count
0   "fake@gmail.com, example@gmail.com"                     2
1   "KingArthur@aol.com, none, SirRobyn@msn.net, Th..."     3
```

Comment: Thanks Joseph.  Though another answer was a bit more concise, this helps me understand how I can address another problem I'm having where the amount of combinations of fields is a small fixed number.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This answer uses https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fake-factory to generate the test data

```
import pandas as pd
from random import randint
from faker import Factory
fake = Factory.create()

def emails():
    emailAdd = [fake.email()]
    for x in range(randint(0,3)):
        emailAdd.append(fake.email())

    return emailAdd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['toaddress', 'ccaddress', 'body'])

for extra in range(10):
    df1 = df1.append(pd.DataFrame({'toaddress':[emails()],'ccaddress':[emails()],'body':fake.text()}),ignore_index=True)

print('toaddress length is {}'.format([len(x) for x in df1.toaddress.values]))
print('ccaddress length is {}'.format([len(x) for x in df1.ccaddress.values]))
```

The last 2 lines is the part that counts your emails.
I wasn't sure if you wanted to check for '@' specifically, maybe you can use fake-factory to generate some test data as an example?

Comment: Thank you!  Mr. F helped me realize an elegant solution, but thanks for turning me onto fake-factory.  I didn't know that existed.  This python newbie is drinking from a fire hose.  Thank you memebrain!