# How many times a character appears in a text of a dataframe form

Tags: python, nlp

I am a begginer in NLP and I have a dataframe which has the following form

```
text                         label 
----                        -----
This is he # first text     first label
This is the # second text   second label 
....                         ....
```

and I want to cound how many times the character '#' appread in this data frame. Could you please help me? I am looking for a generalised code which I cound count either '#' or another character or a word.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32147429/python-count-instances-of-a-specific-character-in-all-rows-within-a-dataframe-c ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dt['text'].apply(lambda x: str.count(x, '#')).sum()`

Comment: Is this meant to be a self-answer or an edit to the question? Please read [answer].

Comment: @Chris self-answer, but I can accept my question in a few hours.

Comment: Then please improve it according to [answer]. Explaining this code snippet would go a long way. Remember, we're here to help future users too so anything you can do to improve clarity will be a help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not the best answer:

```
def count(text, target):
    words = text.split()
    counter = 0
    for word in words:
        if word == target:
            counter += 1
    return counter
df['counter'] = df.apply(lambda row: count(row['text'], target="#"),axis=1)
sum(df["counter"])
```